# app not starting, despite loading successfully

Tags: android

I am getting a strange issue, please see if anyone can help here. Whenever I run my app (either in emulator or in phone), I can see the installation goes successful but the activity does not show up. Following is the message I get in the Console.

```
 ------------------------------
Android Launch!
adb is running normally.
Performing sync
Uploading MyApp.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
Installing MyApp.apk...
Success!
\MyApp\bin\MyApp.apk installed on device
Done!
```

It was running normally before but since yesterday, it has started to behave like this. Ideally after "Success!" statement, the intent gets loaded and MainActivity shows up. But not anymore. I tried restarting/recreating emulator but no help. The only change I had done in my app was to create some xml files for titlebar. I even undid that change but still the same issue. Any help is appreciated.

UPDATED TO ADD MANIFEST FILE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.bfp.MyApp"
android:versionCode="12"
android:versionName="2.5" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="10" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<permission
    android:name="com.bfp.MyApp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.bfp.MyApp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"

    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.bfp.MyApp.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.bfp.MyApp.TestQuizActivity"
        android:parentActivityName="com.bfp.MyApp.MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.bfp.MyApp.MainActivity" />
    </activity>


 <service android:name="com.bfp.MyApp.GCMIntentService" />

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="com.bfp.MyApp" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="com.bfp.MyApp" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <activity
        android:name="com.bfp.MyApp.RegisterActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop" />


    <activity
        android:name="com.bfp.MyApp.BaseActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: please post your stacktrace from logcat

Comment: And the manifest please.

Comment: There are no messages in logcat. The manifest file was untouched since I last ran it successfully. let me post it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Does your app run correctly when you run it from the phone directly? If so, perhaps you accidently changed the run configuration from eclipse to launch other activity than you MainActivity. This affect running from eclipse via the debug interface.

Comment: I tried running it on phone(from eclipse with phone connected as device through USB). Still the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem was more while running the app from eclipse. Installing the apk file in phone was working fine. I deleted the AVDs and recreated them. Also I noticed that my app had reference to android ver 4.3 whereas the intel atom image was not available for that version. hence I downgraded it to 4.2.2. With these changes done, the app started loading normally. Not really what was the root cause, but something to do with the AVD was the issue.